# Kendo Editor - Function for thumbnailUrl is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, kendo-editor

I'm trying to use the image upload feature of kendo editor. Image uploading is working fine, but the thumbnails in the browse window is not showing correctly. For achieving this, I'm trying to call a function in thumbnail attribute. But, this is not firing. Please find the code snippet below and help me to find the issue.

`transport: {
                    read: "api/imagebrowser/read",
                    thumbnailUrl: function (path, name) {
                        alert('inside thumbnail');
                        //return "api/imagebrowser/thumbnail?path=" + path + file;
                    },
                    uploadUrl: "api/imagebrowser/upload",
                    imageUrl: "Content/Images/{0}"
                }`

I'm using WEB API and angularjs. Any other suggestions to show the thumbnails are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
thumbnailUrl: function (path, name) {
    path = "yourAPI/read" + "/" + name;
    return path;
}
```

default path is "", and name is fileName.

I think you already solved...
Good luck.